# JS timer not resetting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Stopwatch resets, since clicking start again stop watch begins the counting at zero. However, I would like to show zero out as well, similar to when the page is first refreshed. Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/xmp5fq50/

```
var Stopwatch = function(elem, options) {
var timer = createTimer(),
startButton = createButton("Start", start, "start"),
stopButton = createButton("Stop", stop, "stop"),
resetButton = createButton("Reset", reset, "reset"),
offset,
clock,
interval;
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code directly in the question and format it appropriately.  Questions where the required code is only in an external resource are considered off-topic here on stack overflow for a variety of reasons and can be closed.

Comment: Trying to but code too long. Only put a teaser in so people could see what I was starting on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think it's too long?  I'm not aware of a limit that would be hit with only 135 lines of code.  Plus, you probably don't need all that code to illustrate your question.

Comment: something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/roullie666/xmp5fq50/3/)?

Comment: @roullie - You really should NOT offer a solution to a question that does not yet include the relevant code in the actual question.  These kind of questions tend to end up being useless as a reference over time.  We need to encourage the OP to make their question fit the rules of the site before we answer it.  That's how someone new to the site learns the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for it to go back to it's original state then you can simply remove `render(0)` from the reset function and replace with `timer.innerHTML = '';` This is possible since you are simply just needing to reset to starting state which would be an empty span.

If you wanted to reset to 0 and display that then you could do `timer.innerHTML = '0.0';` instead so that the span resets to a 0 state rather than hiding it.

The resulting function would look something like:

```
function reset() {
    clock = 0;
    timer.innerHTML = '0.0';
}
```

[I have adjusted the JSFiddle to show you.](https://jsfiddle.net/mxqe9t0b/)

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome! If it works for you then please mark as the answer. Working on my reputation :)